# What is the proper way to add MANY images to WP8 map?

Tags: windows-phone-8

In building a program that displays a map, I have two sliders:

1. that changes the map's pitch
2. that rotates the map's heading
   And, two Buttons that change the Zoom_Level of the map

I have close to 200 images that need to be displayed on the map at any given time based on the zoom level.  (each one is click-able)

With so many Images, I'm getting an:
    "A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll"
thrown.

Many of these Images are the same - just displayed in different places. I find it very inefficient that I need to initialize each different Image separately and place it inside it's own MapOverlay instead of referencing a globally constructed Image and referencing it when I need it. (there is also a problem with Clearing the Map.Layers when the Images are defined globally).

Is there a better way to add many Images to a map?

After I hit about 50 Images I get the OutOfMemoryException (the Images need to be defined separately so that they are square in dimension for the rotating to work properly).

Does it matter how the Images are added to the Project/App ("Build Action" or the "Copy to Output Directory")? Would it be better to have them in Isolated Storage? Would this make a difference?

Here is the code I'm currently using to add Images:

```
        MapLayer pinLayerZoom12 = new MapLayer();

        MapOverlay pinOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        // Add the location of the Pushpin using latitude and longitude.
        pinOverlay.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(49.33783000, -0.45215600);
        Image pinOverlayImage = new Image();
        pinOverlayImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/Hedgehog.png", UriKind.Relative));
        pinOverlay.Content = pinOverlayImage;
        pinOverlay.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
        pinOverlayImage.Opacity = 0.8;
        pinOverlayImage.Height = 10;
        pinOverlayImage.Width = 10;
        pinOverlayImage.Tap += pinOverlayImage_Tap;
        pinLayerZoom12.Add(pinOverlay);

        MapOverlay pinOverlay2 = new MapOverlay();
        // Add the location of the Pushpin using latitude and longitude., 
        pinOverlay2.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(49.33783000, -0.44547083);
        Image pinOverlay2Image = new Image();
        pinOverlay2Image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("images/Hedgehog.png", UriKind.Relative));
        pinOverlay2.Content = pinOverlay2Image;
        pinOverlay2.PositionOrigin = new Point(0.0, 0.0);
        pinOverlay2Image.Opacity = 0.8;
        pinOverlay2Image.Height = 10;
        pinOverlay2Image.Width = 10;
        pinOverlayImage.Tap += pinOverlayImage2_Tap;
        pinLayerZoom12.Add(pinOverlay2);

        // Add the layer to the map
        map1.Layers.Add(pinLayerZoom12);
```

Thank you for any help you can give me!

Comment: Do you really need 200 images at once? Can anyone distinguish the images with 200? A better solution would be to show the images as you zoom in closer, and only the ones in your visible extent

Comment: That's a great point. Is there a way to add more images dynamically as a user 'pans' and moves the map? So, as a new area gets loaded into the visible screen, the images dynamically show up on the screen?